# CME and 2951 embedded service engine issue

Tags: cisco, router

I have a client with CME on a 2951 router.  They lost the login creds for CME and I attempted to reset the login via creating a session to the embedded service engine.  When I tried to do this I realized for some reason there was no IP address assigned to the ESE and therefore I could not connect to it.  I then tried to do an IP unnumbered assigned to the LAN interface on the router.  When I tried to connect to it this time it said open but could not type anything.  What is the best practice for giving the ESE an IP so that you can create a session to it?  Is there another way to reset or recover a login for CME?  Any info will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: From your question seems you have access to the router CLI. Isn´t it?  If so, CME is embedded in the IOS itself and you can manage it via CLI with the router´s credential. Seems to me you lost credentials for CUE. Please make your question more clear, so we can give you an answer.

Comment: Hello.  Yes I do have access to the routers CLI.  When I try create a session to the service engine at first it was saying there is no ip address assigned to the service engine. When I did IP unnumbered on the service-engine of the LAN interface it will say trying.....open when I create a session but it won't go any further.  What I am needing to do is reset the login creditals to the CME GUI as I was under the impression that doing it through the service engine was the only way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments I understand you want to log into your Cisco Unity Express (CUE) via CLI session to do password recovery.

Next is a sample configuration for NME with CUE:

```
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 description LAN
 ip address 10.10.10.5 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 media-type rj45
!
!
!
interface Integrated-Service-Engine2/0
 ip unnumbered GigabitEthernet0/0
 service-module ip address 10.10.10.10 255.255.255.0
 !Application: CUE Running on NME
 service-module ip default-gateway 10.10.10.1
 no keepalive
!
!
ip route 10.10.10.10 255.255.255.255 Integrated-Service-Engine2/0
!
```

You can access router´s CLI in 10.10.10.5 and CUE GUI in 10.10.10.10. Also, to log into CUE CLI you can do it from router CLI by running the following command:

```
router#service-module Integrated-Service-Engine 2/0 session
Trying 10.10.10.10, 2130 ... Open
```

From your comments I think you are reaching this point. Once there, press enter twice and you should get the the CUE prompt:

```
router#service-module Integrated-Service-Engine 2/0 session
Trying 10.10.10.10, 2130 ... Open

UnityExpress#
UnityExpress# 
UnityExpress#
```

Just in case you need it, the process to do password reset in CUE GUI is documented here:

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/voice-unified-communications/unity-express/64234-cue-gui-pw.html

In brief, you have to create a new user, assign a password to it and add this user to group "Administrators", using the following commands:

```
UnityExpress>
UnityExpress>user Administrator create 
UnityExpress>
UnityExpress>user Administrator group Administrators
UnityExpress>
UnityExpress>user Administrator password cisco
UnityExpress>
```

Comment: Actually I figured it out.  It was using ICM0/0 instead of the embedded service engine. Your answer was great and I will give you credit!  Thanks for your help!